# Using mpv video player from the command line, which is the option for selecting a specific audio card?

Tags: linux, audio, media-player

I am using the **mpv** media player under Linux (Ubuntu).

I would like to select a specific sound card but I do not understand the syntax of the command line for doing that (--ao option?).

The output of command `aplay -l` gives me a card number which I want to use for selecting the correct audio card.

Thanks.

Comment: Look here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=153613

Comment: @Corluk: nothing about command line arguments of **mpv** here.

Comment: Oh, misread the question. I'm sorry.